# Vim always asks for password

Tags: vim, spf13vim

I just installed the spf13 plugin suite and now whenever I try to save a new file it asks me for a password:

[image]

This appears about a second after I type `:w`.  What is going on and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

As this appears after a file write, it is probably triggered by on the `BufWritePost` event.

```
:au BufWritePost
```

lists all potential candidates. As romainl has commented, using a distribution appears comfortable, but puts you at risk for unwanted effects, as you're giving up control of your config. If you can resolve this issue on your own, or find prompt help by the distribution's maintainer / community, okay. But if you struggle with this, re-think whether keeping the distribution is really worth it.

Vim "distributions" like *spf-13* and *Janus* lure you with a quick install and out-of-the-box settings, but you pay the price with increased complexity (you need to understand both Vim's runtime loading scheme and the arbitrary conventions of the distribution) and inflexibility (the distribution may make some things easier, but other things very difficult). Vim is incredibly customizable, using someone else's customization makes no sense.

Comment: The value of distributions is IMO to see an example of different ways to organize your vim files and take useful bits here and there.

Comment: @majkinetor Those useful bits can also be taken from blog posts or published dotfile repositories. For plugin organization, there's already a consensus: bundles, as implemented by various file managers.

Comment: distribution is published dotfile repository, nothing more. Yes, bundles are the way to go but there are still good moments about using them. NeoBundle has tones of options for example and documentation is lacking details. @ingo-karkat

Comment: @majkinetor Then we have different definitions of "distribution"; the ones I've mentioned bring their own conventions and configuration places; i.e. you cannot simply use `.vimrc` any more.

Comment: @majkinetor, the difference between a "distribution" and one's `.vim` on GitHub is that latter is just put there for its author's convenience and the former comes with its own install/update mechanism, some superficial documentation/screenshots and hyperbolic marketing speak designed to make newbies believe that configuring Vim is hard and time-consuming and that it should be left to pros. "Distributions" prevent learning, thinking, making experiments and *actively* prevent you from getting help from other Vimmers whom didn't fell in that trap. Seriously, WTF with `vimrc.before/vimrc.after`?

Comment: Ah, @romainl, I knew it was just a matter of time until you **had** to chime in to this discussion :-)

Comment: @romainl Yes, I agree, but I checked all distributions and took good beats from them. Those are most of the time, the most advanced vimrcs I have seen. `before/after` is needed in that scenario - you don't want to change distribution vimrc as you will want to update it and not hassle with merge. I was even thinking to add it to my own vimrc because I use vim on many different places and some of them have custom line or two but I like to update them all to my latest repo version.

Comment: There is no need to condemn distributions anyway. Sometimes its just what some people need. I wish I had some distro at the beginning when I didn't know sht about vim. Like this I replaced my complete vimrc 3 times and each time I was rediscovering something that was already there in some distro. You can always switch when you feel advanced enough. This is easy to do if distro doesn't change defaults too much.